# When two Rails engines define a method of the same name, which one overrides

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

If a Rails app has two engines that define the same method, which version "wins"? How is it decided which one gets executed when the method's name is evoked?

For example, both [the Rails engine blacklight](https://github.com/projectblacklight/blacklight/blob/c100a3fc5c79d5c27b41900d9480ba74fe455f59/app/models/blacklight/suggest_search.rb) and [another Rails engine meant to modify Blacklight's functionality](https://github.com/trln/trln_argon/blob/master/app/models/blacklight/suggest_search.rb) define a method like this:

```
module Blacklight
  class SuggestSearch
    def suggestions
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

The method definition is the same in the two engines but with `...` in place of different content. The second of the engines is meant to override the functionality of the first.

The two engines are used in the same app, like this:

```
gem 'blacklight'
gem 'trln_argon'
```

How does rails know which engine modifies the other? How is the second engine's definition of `suggestions` made to prevail?

Comment: Order of operations which ever one is loaded last this is the definition that will be used

Comment: @engineersmnky I somehow assumed it couldn't be that simple! Thank you